# How can i pass data from my code to sandbox in node.js

Tags: node.js

i am using https://github.com/gf3/sandbox#readme but i am not getting that how can i pass some data from my code to javascript code through this sandbox. for example

```js
var s = new sandBox();
s.run("(function(name) { return 'Hi there, ' + name + '!'; })('Fabio')", function(output) {
    console.log("Example 2: " + output.result + "\n")
})
```

now i want to pass some data to this function how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

It does not have any clean way to pass arguments. However, since you are passing code as a string anyway, you can simply add the arguments directly to the string:

```
var arg = 'Hello';
var code = "(function(name) { return 'Hi there, ' + name + '!'; })("+ JSON.stringify(arg) +")"
s.run(code, ...);
```

I'm using `JSON.stringify` to ensure that the string is a valid JS expression.

Comment: does it only work for string or this can be used to pass any objects like obj = {name:"fsdfs"} something like that.

Comment: can you guide me about how to safely run untrusted javascript code in node.js when I need the code to have access to my data/code though sandbox environment is this one is the right way or there are some other ways which are more appropriate for this.

Comment: This is far outside the scope of a comment (or this question). Please post a separate question for this.

Comment: i have posted it but none has replied yet. i only asked you because i thought you might have idea.